# Python Django - Uploading a file from the shell

Tags: python, django, shell

I am trying to upload a file from a shell to one of my django models in the following manner:

```
a = Post(name=name, content=content)
a.attachment.save('some.pdf', File(open('some.pdf', 'r')))
```

But I keep getting the following error:
`TypeError: must be convertible to a buffer, not FieldFile`. I looked at other posts and could not find any solution that solves this problem.

I am using Python 2.7 and Django 1.10.
I would really appreciate any help.

**EDIT:** The problem was not with the way I was storing the file but was with my post-save signals. Sorry and thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
f = open('some.pdf', 'r')
a.attachment = File(f)
a.save()
f.close()
```

Comment: Hey, that does not solve the problem. It throws the exact same error. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @RishabhRanawat please post the `Post` model.